# A CSS class is added to an element by JS at runtime, but its properties are not applied. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been monitoring what CSS classes properties are applied to `.header` when the window is scrolled down enough that `.view` is no longer visible. The class `scroll-header` IS added to `.header`, but the associated CSS properties ARE NOT applied. They question is why and how do I fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("script.js is detected"); //check

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log("window onscroll being called."); //check
    if ($("div.view").visible(true)) {
      console.log("YES if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )"); //check
      $(".header").removeClass(".scroll-header");
    } else {
      console.log("NO if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )"); //check
      $(".header").addClass(".scroll-header");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.view {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: crimson;
}
.second {
  height: 2500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.scroll-header {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
* {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>
<div class="view">.</div>
<div class="header">.</div>
<div class="second">.</div>
<div class="scroll-header" style="bottom:0px;">.</div>
```

Comment: `.visible` is not a function

Comment: @hjpotter92 There is a JQuery plugin included. The question is resolved. You can see the accepted answer if interested. Thans for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in comment, `.visible` is not a function of jquery. Although you can use below code to detect your dom element is visible or not:

```
if ($("#yourElem").is(":visible") == true) { 
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```

As you are using jquery.visible plugin. Your code is wrong in javascript. Correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("script.js is detected"); //check

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log("window onscroll being called."); //check
    if ($("div.view").visible(true)) {
      console.log("YES if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )"); //check
      $(".header").removeClass("scroll-header");
    } else {
      console.log("NO if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )"); //check
      $(".header").addClass("scroll-header");
    }
  });

});
```

You were adding .scroll-header instead of scroll-header

Comment: Notice they included a plugin: `http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js`. They might simply be misusing this plugin.

Comment: @Tobsta No, I am not misusing it, you can see its use [here](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery. Please see that all I have done in JS is either added a class or removed it. It IS added/removed as expected (I checked that in the inspector of Firefox), as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Solace Ok. Note that I haven't actually looked at the plugin.

Comment: @solace, please check my answer. Error were in addClass and removeClass.

Comment: @Tobsta OK. Thanks for pointing out. Your comment definitely helped, I upvoted it. Thank you again.